# Using a .html file to run a .exe file from a browser

Tags: html, flash, exe

I wanna know how do I create a .html file to run a autorun.exe so that it will run on Mac OS and Windows. The autorun.exe is actually a file that execute all the flash content inside a CD.

Inside the CD there is content folder(where all the flash file is), fscommand folder, autorun.exe, autorun.inf, start.exe, and a .ico file.

Comment: No. 1) You cannot run executables from HTML without being asked by browser, whether you really want it 2) You cannot run the same executable on Windows and MacOS simultaneously. 3) If it's Flash and HTML, why are you messing with executable at all???

Comment: Autorun.exe does not work on Mac OS (and current generation Macs don't have CD drives anymore either)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452289/creating-a-dual-mac-win-autorun-cd

Answer (score 1):

NO you may get problems running an exe on MacOS. They require a win32 platform, which MacOS never has been ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but try to follow the link in the first answer..

[Execute exe-file from html-page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506244/execute-exe-file-from-html-page)